# Submodel not executing within main model

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder

My main model contains the following:

- Workspace variable `Input GDB`
- Feature class `Input Feature Class`
- SubModel 1 that produces `OUTPUT` feature class

[image: Submodel]
`Parse Path` is used to obtain the name from the input feature class and is stored in the variable `Name`. This is used as an inline variable for the various outputs of the processes inside `SubModel 1`. The workspace variable is also used as an inline variable.

My problem now is that the submodel is not executing. It accepted the input feature class and executed successfully on its own. When I added it to the main model it now refuses to run, even with exactly the same input.

Comment: Could you display the submodel too?

Comment: The submodel has the input and output feature class as model parameters, and performs a series of operations such as `Add Field`, `Calculate Field`, `Join` etc. Maybe it's the fact that it uses `Name` as inline variable for the outputs within the submodel? Initially I just used the `Input GDB` as an inline variable and it worked fine. It's when I added `Input Feature Class` that it stopped working.

Comment: It looks like Name is set as a prerequisite, rather than as an input.  Is it supposed to be an input?

Answer (score 4):

I've run into this same problem.  For some reason, ArcGIS isn't reading the submodel as valid.  What you need to do is open up the submodel and set all the parameters so that they point to dummy files.  You'll be overriding all the inputs anyway, so this *shouldn't* matter, but ModelBuilder will refuse to run a model that it thinks doesn't have valid inputs and won't stop to check if the inputs from the main model make the submodel valid.  The results you get before the thing crashes should work great as those dummy files, since they'll have all the fields you need in them.

Re-import the submodel to the main model.  If it works, the submodel will be colored in.